# CSS - how to align different font-sizes to each other?

Tags: css, alignment, font-size

I have a small problem with some CSS -> [Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/earle37/Eh8TB/)

Simple button:

```
<button type="reset" id="reset-btn">Reset</button>
```

CSS rule:

```
button#reset-btn:after{
    content:" <<";
    font-size:2em;
}
```

As you can see the "<<" is getting generated through CSS. Is there a way to align these two different font sizes to each other so that the text next to the bigger "<<" is at the vertical center of the button?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the text within a `span` tag and then apply the style `vertical-align: middle` to both the `button` and `span`

**HTML**

```
<button type="reset" id="reset-btn"><span id="reset-text">Reset</span></button>
```

**CSS**

```
button#reset-btn:after{
    content:" <<";
    font-size:2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#reset-text{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Eh8TB/3/

Answer (score 2):

Add the `vertical-align` property:

```
button#reset-btn:after {
content:" <<";
font-size:2em;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try...

```
button#reset-btn:after, button#reset-btn{
font-size:1em;
```

}

Add that under your JS fiddle CSS.

Comment: Hi, it already got solved in another answer, but thank you for your respond!

Comment: you should post the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

I would just give the content a position:

```
button#reset-btn:after{
    content:" <<";
    font-size:2em;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kevin's answer works nice when no text wrapping is needing, but if your button has a couple more words and starts a new line it doesn't look so good.

I ended up wrapping each font in a dive ad use this css for both of them

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle
```

Here's what I mean

**Working Solution** http://jsfiddle.net/Eh8TB/71/